# What happens to the encryption key on "Forget SD card" action?

Tags: adoptable-storage, disk-encryption

Recently my SD card, formatted as internal storage, got inaccessible for the phone (Moto G5) for some reason.

If "Forget SD card" option was selected, does it wipe out the SD card encryption key from `/data/misc/vold`?

Does it make sense to root the phone and try to extract the key?

Comment: I never did that, but in my opinion key would have been deleted after forgetting SD card.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Adoptable storage encryption key without root access after I "forget it"](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/181476/how-to-get-adoptable-storage-encryption-key-without-root-access-after-i-forget)